# RVM Ruby install fails in CentOS while configuring

Tags: ruby, centos, rvm

I am unable to install new version's of Ruby in CentOS through RVM. The installation seems to get error while configuring.

I have tried installing different version of Ruby's, always get the same error.

**My Error log**

```
[root@dev src]# rvm install 1.9.3
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: redhat/6/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p551.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for redhat.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p551, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #extracting ruby-1.9.3-p551 to /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p551....
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #applying patch /usr/local/rvm/patches/ruby/GH-488.patch.
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #applying patch /usr/local/rvm/patches/ruby/1.9.3/CVE-2015-1855-p484.patch.
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #applying patch /usr/local/rvm/patches/ruby/1.9.3/update-autoconf.patch.
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #applying patch /usr/local/rvm/patches/ruby/ssl_no_ec2m.patch.
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #configuring..
Error running './configure --prefix=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551 --disable-install-doc --enable-shared',
showing last 15 lines of /usr/local/rvm/log/1467903754_ruby-1.9.3-p551/configure.log
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... /lib/cpp
configure: error: in `/usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p551':
configure: error: C preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check
See `config.log' for more details
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

**Config.log**

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by configure, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551 --disable-install-doc --enable-shared

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = dev
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #1 SMP Fri Apr 11 17:27:00 EDT 2014

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = x86_64
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /data06/devops/apps/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin
PATH: /home/devops/workspace/apps/node-v0.12.7-linux-x64/bin
PATH: /data05/java/jdk1.7.0_75/bin
PATH: /usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /home/devops/bin
PATH: /usr/local/rvm/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2800: checking build system type
configure:2814: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2882: checking host system type
configure:2895: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2915: checking target system type
configure:2928: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:3153: checking for gcc
configure:3169: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:3180: result: gcc
configure:3409: checking for C compiler version
configure:3418: gcc --version >&5
gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:3429: $? = 0
configure:3418: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-java-maintainer-mode --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libjava-multilib --with-ppl --with-cloog --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17) (GCC)
configure:3429: $? = 0
configure:3418: gcc -V >&5
gcc: '-V' option must have argument
configure:3429: $? = 1
configure:3418: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: unrecognized option '-qversion'
gcc: no input files
configure:3429: $? = 1
configure:3449: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3471: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
configure:3475: $? = 0
configure:3523: result: yes
configure:3526: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:3528: result: a.out
configure:3534: checking for suffix of executables
configure:3541: gcc -o conftest    conftest.c  >&5
configure:3545: $? = 0
configure:3567: result:
configure:3589: checking whether we are cross compiling
configure:3597: gcc -o conftest    conftest.c  >&5
configure:3601: $? = 0
configure:3608: ./conftest
configure:3612: $? = 0
configure:3627: result: no
configure:3632: checking for suffix of object files
configure:3654: gcc -c   conftest.c >&5
configure:3658: $? = 0
configure:3679: result: o
configure:3683: checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler
configure:3702: gcc -c   conftest.c >&5
configure:3702: $? = 0
configure:3711: result: yes
configure:3720: checking whether gcc accepts -g
configure:3740: gcc -c -g  conftest.c >&5
configure:3740: $? = 0
configure:3781: result: yes
configure:3798: checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89
configure:3861: gcc  -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:3861: $? = 0
configure:3874: result: none needed
configure:3952: checking for g++
configure:3968: found /usr/bin/g++
configure:3979: result: g++
configure:4006: checking for C++ compiler version
configure:4015: g++ --version >&5
g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:4026: $? = 0
configure:4015: g++ -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-java-maintainer-mode --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libjava-multilib --with-ppl --with-cloog --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17) (GCC)
configure:4026: $? = 0
configure:4015: g++ -V >&5
g++: '-V' option must have argument
configure:4026: $? = 1
configure:4015: g++ -qversion >&5
g++: unrecognized option '-qversion'
g++: no input files
configure:4026: $? = 1
configure:4030: checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler
configure:4049: g++ -c   conftest.cpp >&5
configure:4049: $? = 0
configure:4058: result: yes
configure:4067: checking whether g++ accepts -g
configure:4087: g++ -c -g  conftest.cpp >&5
configure:4087: $? = 0
configure:4128: result: yes
configure:4157: checking how to run the C preprocessor
configure:4188: gcc -E  conftest.c
In file included from /usr/include/bits/posix1_lim.h:157,
                 from /usr/include/limits.h:145,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/include/limits.h:122,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/include/syslimits.h:7,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/include/limits.h:11,
                 from conftest.c:11:
/usr/include/bits/local_lim.h:39:26: error: linux/limits.h: No such file or directory
configure:4188: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define CANONICALIZATION_FOR_MATHN 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #ifdef __STDC__
| # include <limits.h>
| #else
| # include <assert.h>
| #endif
|                    Syntax error
configure:4188: gcc -E  conftest.c
In file included from /usr/include/bits/posix1_lim.h:157,
                 from /usr/include/limits.h:145,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/include/limits.h:122,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/include/syslimits.h:7,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/include/limits.h:11,
                 from conftest.c:11:
/usr/include/bits/local_lim.h:39:26: error: linux/limits.h: No such file or directory
configure:4188: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define CANONICALIZATION_FOR_MATHN 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #ifdef __STDC__
| # include <limits.h>
| #else
| # include <assert.h>
| #endif
|                    Syntax error
configure:4188: gcc -E -traditional-cpp  conftest.c
In file included from /usr/include/features.h:362,
                 from /usr/include/assert.h:38,
                 from conftest.c:14:
/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:32: error: #error "You need a ISO C conforming compiler to use the glibc headers"
configure:4188: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define CANONICALIZATION_FOR_MATHN 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #ifdef __STDC__
| # include <limits.h>
| #else
| # include <assert.h>
| #endif
|                    Syntax error
configure:4188: gcc -E -traditional-cpp  conftest.c
In file included from /usr/include/features.h:362,
                 from /usr/include/assert.h:38,
                 from conftest.c:14:
/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:32: error: #error "You need a ISO C conforming compiler to use the glibc headers"
configure:4188: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define CANONICALIZATION_FOR_MATHN 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #ifdef __STDC__
| # include <limits.h>
| #else
| # include <assert.h>
| #endif
|                    Syntax error
configure:4188: /lib/cpp  conftest.c
In file included from /usr/include/bits/posix1_lim.h:157,
                 from /usr/include/limits.h:145,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/include/limits.h:122,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/include/syslimits.h:7,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/include/limits.h:11,
                 from conftest.c:11:
/usr/include/bits/local_lim.h:39:26: error: linux/limits.h: No such file or directory
configure:4188: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define CANONICALIZATION_FOR_MATHN 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #ifdef __STDC__
| # include <limits.h>
| #else
| # include <assert.h>
| #endif
|                    Syntax error
configure:4188: /lib/cpp  conftest.c
In file included from /usr/include/bits/posix1_lim.h:157,
                 from /usr/include/limits.h:145,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/include/limits.h:122,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/include/syslimits.h:7,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/include/limits.h:11,
                 from conftest.c:11:
/usr/include/bits/local_lim.h:39:26: error: linux/limits.h: No such file or directory
configure:4188: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define CANONICALIZATION_FOR_MATHN 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #ifdef __STDC__
| # include <limits.h>
| #else
| # include <assert.h>
| #endif
|                    Syntax error
configure:4227: result: /lib/cpp
configure:4247: /lib/cpp  conftest.c
In file included from /usr/include/bits/posix1_lim.h:157,
                 from /usr/include/limits.h:145,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/include/limits.h:122,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/include/syslimits.h:7,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/include/limits.h:11,
                 from conftest.c:11:
/usr/include/bits/local_lim.h:39:26: error: linux/limits.h: No such file or directory
configure:4247: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define CANONICALIZATION_FOR_MATHN 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #ifdef __STDC__
| # include <limits.h>
| #else
| # include <assert.h>
| #endif
|                    Syntax error
configure:4247: /lib/cpp  conftest.c
In file included from /usr/include/bits/posix1_lim.h:157,
                 from /usr/include/limits.h:145,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/include/limits.h:122,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/include/syslimits.h:7,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/include/limits.h:11,
                 from conftest.c:11:
/usr/include/bits/local_lim.h:39:26: error: linux/limits.h: No such file or directory
configure:4247: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define CANONICALIZATION_FOR_MATHN 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #ifdef __STDC__
| # include <limits.h>
| #else
| # include <assert.h>
| #endif
|                    Syntax error
configure:4277: error: in `/usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p551':
configure:4279: error: C preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ac_cv_c_compiler_gnu=yes
ac_cv_cxx_compiler_gnu=yes
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
```

I have verified, that i have cpp installed.

```
[root@dev src]# cpp --version
cpp (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Installed GCC package

```
[root@dev src]# yum list | grep gcc
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
This system is registered to Red Hat Subscription Management, but is not receiving updates. You can use subscription-manager to assign subscriptions.
gcc.x86_64                          4.4.7-17.el6           @rhel-x86_64-server-6
gcc-c++.x86_64                      4.4.7-17.el6           @rhel-x86_64-server-6
libgcc.i686                         4.4.7-17.el6           @rhel-x86_64-server-6
libgcc.x86_64                       4.4.7-17.el6           @rhel-x86_64-server-6
compat-gcc-34.x86_64                3.4.6-19.el6           redhatdvdiso
compat-gcc-34-c++.x86_64            3.4.6-19.el6           redhatdvdiso
compat-gcc-34-g77.x86_64            3.4.6-19.el6           redhatdvdiso
gcc-gfortran.x86_64                 4.4.7-17.el6           rhel-x86_64-server-6
gcc-gnat.x86_64                     4.4.7-17.el6           rhel-x86_64-server-6
gcc-java.x86_64                     4.4.7-17.el6           rhel-x86_64-server-6
gcc-objc.x86_64                     4.4.7-17.el6           rhel-x86_64-server-6
gcc-objc++.x86_64                   4.4.7-17.el6           rhel-x86_64-server-6
```

Comment: What is in `config.log`?

Comment: I have updated question with config.log

Comment: Did you follow [the install instructions](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) provided by RVM's authors? RVM, when installed normally, will reside in ~/.rvm, not /usr/local/... and the authors recommend using the normal install, not a "global" install. Unless you are a seasoned sysadmin, I'd recommend doing the normal installation.

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed it. I just ran "yum update" command, in the output i noticed the following line

```
glibc-headers-2.12-1.80.el6.x86_64 has missing requires of kernel-headers
glibc-headers-2.12-1.80.el6.x86_64 has missing requires of kernel-headers >= ('0', '2.2.1', None)
```

After this, i installed kernel-header using

```
yum install kernel-header
```

After this everything, worked fine